# How do I install boot camp on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, mac, boot-camp

I have installed Windows 7 on my Mac (running 10.5 Leopard) using Boot Camp.

Windows 7 is functioning half decent but some features are not working such as wireless. When I try to install the drivers from the CD it says that it only works with Windows XP and Vista.

How can I install the Boot Camp drivers if I don't have Mac OS 10.6?

Comment: You confuse the device (a Mac) with the operating system (Mac OS X).

Answer (score 1):

Go to the CD files from the Computer menu.

Locate the Setup File it may easily be called Setup.exe.

Right click -> and go to the Compatability Tab. Choose compatability for Windows Vista.

Alternatively you can right click the Setup.exe and click Troubleshoot Compatability...

Hope this helps.

Comment: The Vista drivers should work with Windows 7, and it's just the point of getting past the version checker on the Boot Camp installer.